# Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Tags: java, junit, parameters

I have written a test class, such that is following

```
public class MyParameterizedClassTest extends BaseRepositoryTest {
    private int multiplierA;
    private int multiplierB;
    public MyParameterizedClassTest(int multiplierA) {
        this.multiplierA = multiplierA;

    }   

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() { 
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 5 }, { 121 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiplyException() {
        assertEquals("Result", multiplierA * multiplierA,multiply(multiplierA));
    }

    public int multiply(int a){
        return a*a;
    }
 }
```

And My BaseRepositoryTest class is following

```
@RunWith (Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTest extends
    AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {



    @Inject
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Transaction transaction;

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (SessionException se) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        getSession().close();
    }

    @Before
    public void baseSetUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

When I run my test class it shows like,

```
 Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor:at 
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor
```

I want to make a test method with @parameters,so please  Can anyone please help to find the solution

Comment: Looks like the wrong test runner is executing your task. We need to figure out why that is to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure your classes are all correctly compiled. Your exception mentions the `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`, but a `Parameterized` is not a subclass of `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`. See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html. Seems that your compiled code does not contain `@RunWith (Parameterized. class)`

Comment: yes I tried with @RunWith (Parameterized. class),Now it shows java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.kgfsl.collections.core.security.BaseRepositoryTest.getSession(BaseRepositoryTest.java:45)  at com.kgfsl.collections.core.security.BaseRepositoryTest.setUp(BaseRepositoryTest.java:54)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: @Duncan: My answer was surely based on a basic java knowledge :
[Java Constructors-Note](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors), See the Note.

If a class defines an explicit constructor, it no longer has a default constructor to set the state of the objects.
If such a class requires a default constructor, its implementation must be provided. Any attempt to call the default constructor will be a compile time error if an explicit default constructor is not provided in such a case.

Comment: @RenéLink it perfectly works for me rene. thanks for the solution

Answer (score 34):

### JUnit 4 vs Jupiter - Wrong import may be causing the problem

**TL;DR** import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test`

---

I had this issue when I imported the wrong `Test` class.

While a constructor was using JUnit 5 features, I imported the old `org.junit.Test` rather than `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

Answer (score 10):

I think the problem is that you defined two test runners. One by yourself `@RunWith (Parameterized. class)` and one that comes with  spring, because an `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` defines a `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

Since Junit can only deal with one `@RunWith` you can only use `@Parameterized` or `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests`. If you want to use both you have to use `@Parameterized` and than do the same logic that a `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` does on your own.

A simple approach can be to just use spring's `org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public abstract class BaseRepositoryTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private TestContextManager testContextManager;

    @Before
    public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

}
```

But this only ensures that the `TestExecutionListener`s are invoked. Spring normally does a lot more like application context caching and so on. Also a tear down method should be implemented that closes the application context.

Comment: Would be even better in a Rule

Comment: @AlexisHassler Yes it would be. The problem with a `Rule` is that you can't easily get the test instance and you need it for the `testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);`

Comment: Yeah I tried this code but i got error like java.lang.NullPointerException at com.kgfsl.collections.core.security.BaseRepositoryTest.getSession(BaseRepository‌​Test.java:45) at com.kgfsl.collections.core.security.BaseRepositoryTest.setUp(BaseRepositoryTest.‌​java:54) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: @MdAslam Did you try `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`?

Answer (score 10):

If you're running a single test, make sure that you wrote your test class name correctly

A common mistake that I do is to have a class named 'Foo' and a test class named

> 'FooTest'

and run a single unit test with

> 'Foo'

instead of 'FooTest'

If 'Foo' has a public constructor with arguments I get the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
```

Comment: Yes! This was me! Thanks. Needed to add `Test` to the end of my test invocation command.

Comment: This happened with me when I was using a pattern to find the list of tests. I had `**/*FooTest*`, and `FooTest` had a couple of other nested classes defined inside it. So, the matcher ended up finding `FooTest$InnerClass` and was trying to run it as a test. Fixed by changing to `**/*FooTest.class`

Answer (score 5):

This error is thrown when your class is not defined as public
In your case it is abstract, so it can not be instantiate for testing propouses

Answer (score 1):

Try removing constructor from **MyParameterizedClassTest** class.

I was getting this error when my test class had a public constructor. After removing, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have got one answer,it fix on my machine
JUnit4 -> when u check the exception

```
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:171)
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
```

get inside to first exception

```
protected void validateZeroArgConstructor(List<Throwable> errors) {
    if(!this.getTestClass().isANonStaticInnerClass() && this.hasOneConstructor() && this.getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().getParameterTypes().length != 0) {
        String gripe = "Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor";
        errors.add(new Exception(gripe));
    }

}
```

it will check your constructor is none-parameters or not
Try setter injection or field(->field is not recommended officially)